# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName always returning null

Tags: qt

This is really stumping me, it was working before hand but now it always returns null (therefore not populating).

The code at question is:

```
 imgObjPth = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select Image"), PATH);
```

`imgObjPth` is a `QString` variable, and `QFileDialog` returns `QString`. So how come it's returning null? As I said, this line of code has worked in the past, so I just don't know why today it decides not to work.

**Edit**:

- Cancel is not being pressed.
- I've moved my development from Mac to Ubuntu, but the same issue occurs on my Mac too.
- QT 5.4.2 is used

Comment: Edit: Cancel is not being pressed.

Comment: Have you changed the Qt version? If you make a new small test program, does the same thing occur? Have you tried opening different files? (P.D.: it's better to edit your question and include new details.)

Comment: I've moved my development from Mac to Ubuntu, but the same issue occurs on my Mac too.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I am using version 5.4.2